# csv and excel export functionality in yii

Tags: php, excel, csv, yii

I have export functionality in yii.
Here is my code:
in controller i have query like this:

```
$dateRangeRecords = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT o.orderUniqueID, o.orderCustomerFirstName, o.orderCustomerLastName, o.orderCustomerEmail, o.orderCustomerPhone, o.orderDeliveryAddress, o.orderDeliveryFee, o.deliveryDate,o.orderTax, o.orderProductTotalAmount, o.orderTotalQuantity, o.orderPaymentStatus, o.orderDateAdded, o.orderStatus FROM tbl_order as o, tbl_order_item as item WHERE o.pkOrderID = item.fkOrderID AND o.orderDateAdded >= '".$d_format_one."' AND o.orderDateAdded <= '".$d_format_two."' ");
$arrOrdersRecord = $dateRangeRecords->queryAll();

if (isset($_POST)) {
            if (isset($_POST['csv_export'])) {
                CsvExport::export($arrOrdersRecord, array(
                    "OrderID" => "OrderID",
                    "CustomerFirstName" => "CustomerFirstName",
                    "CustomerLastName" => "CustomerLastName",
                    "CustomerEmail" => "CustomerEmail",
                    "CustomerPhone" => "CustomerPhone",
                    "DeliveryAddress" => "DeliveryAddress",
                    "DeliveryFee" => "DeliveryFee",
                    "DeliveryDate" => "DeliveryDate",
                    "Tax" => "Tax",
                    "TotalAmount" => "TotalAmount",
                    "TotalQuantity" => "TotalQuantity",
                    "PaymentStatus" => "PaymentStatus",
                    "OrderPlacedOn" => "OrderPlacedOn",
                    "Status" => "Status"
                    ), true, 'orders.csv');
            } else if (isset($_POST['excel_export'])) {
                $headerArr = array(
                    "OrderID",
                    "CustomerFirstName",
                    "CustomerLastName",
                    "CustomerEmail",
                    "CustomerPhone",
                    "DeliveryAddress",
                    "DeliveryFee",
                    "DeliveryDate",
                    "Tax",
                    "TotalAmount",
                    "TotalQuantity",
                    "PaymentStatus",
                    "OrderPlacedOn",
                    "Status" => "Status",
                    );
                $rowArr = array();
                $rowArr1 = array();
                $i = 0;

                foreach ($arrOrdersRecord AS $orderRecord) {
                    $j = 0;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->OrderID;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->CustomerFirstName;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->CustomerLastName;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->CustomerEmail;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->CustomerPhone;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->DeliveryAddress;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->DeliveryFee;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->DeliveryDate;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->Tax;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->TotalAmount;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->TotalQuantity;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->PaymentStatus;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->OrderPlacedOn;
                    $rowArr1[$j++] = $orderRecord->Status;

                    $rowArr[$i++] = $rowArr1;
                }
                $this->actionExportToXLS($headerArr, $rowArr, 'orders.xls');
            }
        }
```

In my export function there is a code :

```
public static function export($rows, $coldefs, $boolPrintRows=true, $csvFileName=null, $separator='|')
        {
            $endLine = "\r\n";
            $returnVal = '';

            if($csvFileName != null)
            {
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csvFileName);
                header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            }
            if($boolPrintRows == true){
                $names = '';
                foreach($coldefs as $col=>$config){
                    $names .= $col.$separator;
                }

                $names = rtrim($names,$separator);

                if($csvFileName != null){
                    echo $names.$endLine;
                }
                else
                    $returnVal .= $names.$endLine;
            }
            foreach($rows as $row){
                $r = '';
                foreach($coldefs as $col=>$config){
                    $data = explode("->",$config);
                    $tmp = $row;
                    foreach($data AS $dt){
                        $tmp = $tmp->$dt;
                    }
                    if($tmp!=''){
            //$val = $row->$config;
                        $val = $tmp;
                        $r .= $val.$separator;
                    }else{
                        $val = 'N/A';
                        $r .= $val.$separator;
                    }
                }
                $item = trim(rtrim($r,$separator)).$endLine;
                if($csvFileName != null){
                    echo $item;
                }else{
                    $returnVal .= $item;
                }
            }
            return $returnVal;
        }
```

Problem is i am not able to export the data according to query's result.
data is going to exported like i have provided image. 
Query returns data between 2 dates.
Can any one help?

Thanks.

[image: Displaying data like this in image.]

Comment: it is displaying the header in one row and data as N/A.

Comment: take a look in the exported file with an editor - the N/A are values, but this viewer wont show them

Comment: when i print_r($rows), i can get the values according to query result.

Comment: so in $rows the data is correct, but the produced file doesn't look as expected - in csv you use \t for next cell and \t\n for new line - use them as separator

Comment: not working.. can any one help?

Comment: can you please show us the content of the resulting file, and not a picture of it